# Iterate and copy data from cells with data for cells with no data before that cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Below I have listed the table which I require help on. What I'm trying to do is iterate through the list and copy the date (planned or actual) to the cells before that if they are empty and if there is no data cells after that for a particular type then enter a default date of an year after that.

```
**Category**    **Type**    **Planned Date**    **Actual End Date**
Fruit           Banana      
Fruit           Banana      
Fruit           Banana      
Fruit           Banana                              18/06/2015
Fruit           Banana      
Fruit           Banana      
Fruit           Banana         11/11/2017   
Fruit           Banana      
Fruit           Banana         21/12/2017   
Fruit           Apple       
Fruit           Apple       
Fruit           Apple       
Fruit           Apple                              11/01/2015
Fruit           Apple       
Fruit           Apple       
Fruit           Apple       
Fruit           Apple       
Fruit           Apple         18/12/2015    

Veg            Cucumber     
Veg            Cucumber     

Veg            Cucumber       12/01/2016

Veg            Cucumber     

Veg            Cucumber       25/06/2016    

Veg            Cucumber     
Veg            Cucumber     
Veg            Cucumber       03/11/2016    
Veg            Cucumber
```

I would like it to look like this;

```
**Category**    **Type**    **Planned Date**    **Actual End Date**
Fruit           Banana                              18/06/2015
Fruit           Banana                              18/06/2015
Fruit           Banana                              18/06/2015
Fruit           Banana                              18/06/2015
Fruit           Banana         11/11/2017
Fruit           Banana         11/11/2017
Fruit           Banana         11/11/2017   
Fruit           Banana         21/12/2017
Fruit           Banana         21/12/2017   
Fruit           Apple                              11/01/2015
Fruit           Apple                              11/01/2015
Fruit           Apple                              11/01/2015
Fruit           Apple                              11/01/2015
Fruit           Apple         18/12/2015
Fruit           Apple         18/12/2015
Fruit           Apple         18/12/2015
Fruit           Apple         18/12/2015
Fruit           Apple         18/12/2015    

Veg            Cucumber       12/01/2016
Veg            Cucumber       12/01/2016

Veg            Cucumber       12/01/2016

Veg            Cucumber       25/06/2016

Veg            Cucumber       25/06/2016    

Veg            Cucumber       03/11/2016
Veg            Cucumber       03/11/2016
Veg            Cucumber       03/11/2016    
Veg            Cucumber       01/01/2018
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post any code/formulas that you've attempted to use.  Also kindly clarify: We start at the end of the list, and go up.  If we hit a date, use that date to fill the gap until the next date.  If, starting out, there is no date, use some default date?  So, your `Actual End Date` column will have some default date for all "Veg" category, and some Fruit?  Can you post a completed table, for an example?

Comment: Each item has 9 dates, and they happen in process, e.g. the first item needs to happen before starting the next one, hence if there is an actual date present for 3rd row and the above are empty then I would like the actual date for 3rd row to be copied to actual date column of the above two. Also, if there is no date below for same item then put 1/1/2018.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have written something that should get you started.

```
Sub test()
Dim wsLastRow&, partLastRow&, nextRow&, firstRow&
Dim i&, k&
Dim custDate$

wsLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' this assumes your Column A will have the most data

For k = 3 To 4 ' using columns C and then D
    For i = wsLastRow To 2 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, k)) Then
            custDate = WorksheetFunction.Text(InputBox("What date do you want to put, as there isn't one currently (dd/mm/yyyy)"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
            Cells(i, k).Value = custDate
        Else
            firstRow = i
            partLastRow = Cells(i, k).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Range(Cells(firstRow, k), Cells(partLastRow, k)).FillUp
            i = partLastRow
        End If
    Next i
Next k
End Sub
```

Note: When there's a blank cell, without a previous date, it's going to prompt *each time* for a date.  Let me know how you want to handle such dates, adn we can update that to do something else.  If you walk through the code with <kbd>F8</kbd> you'll see how this works.  Let me know any thoughts/changes necessary!

Edit:

The following code should work, per your comments and final table example.

```
Sub test2()
Dim wsLastRow&, partLastRow&, nextRow&, firstRow&
Dim i&, k&
Dim custDate$
Dim runLastRow As Boolean

runLastRow = False

wsLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    ' this assumes your Column A will have the most data
custDate = WorksheetFunction.Text(InputBox("What date do you want to put, when there isn't one? (dd/mm/yyyy)"), "dd/mm/yyyy")

k = 3                        'noting the "C" Column

For i = wsLastRow To 2 Step -1
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) Then
        Cells(i, k).Value = custDate
        runLastRow = False
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(i, k)) And Cells(i, k + 1) <> "" Then
        k = 4                ' Set the column to use as K
        runLastRow = True
    Else
        k = 3
        runLastRow = True
    End If

    If runLastRow Then
        firstRow = i
        partLastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Cells(i, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, Cells(i, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        Range(Cells(firstRow, k), Cells(partLastRow, k)).FillUp
        i = partLastRow
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, also is it possible to make it copy the date up to with rows where there is no date (planned or actual end date), for example, if there is planned date for 4th apple row but there is an actual end date for 1st apple row and the row 2 and 3 are empty, so in this case I would like it to copy the planned date for 4th apple to row 2 and 3. is it possible to do this in vba?

Comment: @danny - Does the above not do that? Can you restate your question (perhaps add it to your OP with an example?).  Which column do you want the planned date to go in?

Comment: Planned Date is the third column, and the acutal end date is the fourth column, so if there is no date for both the fields then it should look for next available date in both columns and copy to blanks above until next date is available in either of columns.

Comment: By "next available", do you mean the next date going *down* the column, or *up*?

Comment: Since these items are listed in a process so the items would not have happened if the ones before that is not there, so if there is actual end date or planned date then they would be copied up, else if there is none then it would have date of 1/1/2018.

Comment: One final clarification - what does the above macro do that you *don't* want it to do?

Comment: Above macro copies the date up to all the blank cells in one particular column without looking if there is a value present in the actual end date for a particular row because if there is then that value should move up. there is no need of planned date if there is an actual end date.

Comment: @Danny - Can you use your table, that you have in the OP, and also add a "completed" table, with the dates filled in like expected?

Comment: I have added in a table which I want to achieve

Comment: @danny - thanks! That clarified it for me, please see my edit.

Comment: This looks greats, but can I just ask for some more help, since each nine rows refer to same type of item, but this code put the date of apple in banana, so instead can we do if there is no banana dates below then put 1/1/2018 (Custom date).